# How to debug Web2py applications?

Tags: python, debugging, web2py

Is it possible? 
By debug I mean setting breakpoints, inspect values and advance step by step.

Comment: The title says win2py, and the tag says web2py.  Can you correct one of them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do remote debugging of python web apps over TCP/IP with [winpdb](http://winpdb.org/).

(Link appears down as of June 2019. Try [PyPI winpdb](https://pypi.org/project/winpdb/))

Comment: Link          broken ____

Answer (score 8):

I haven't used web2py, but if it runs in a terminal window, you can use standard pdb stuff. Add this line somewhere in your code:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

This will invoke the debugger and break.  Then you can use [PDB](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-pdb.html) commands: n to step to the next line, l to list code, s to step into a function, p to print values, etc.

Answer (score 8):

One can debug applications built on Web2py using the following set-up:

1. Eclipse IDE
2. Install Pydev into Eclipse
3. Set Breakpoints on your code as needed
4. Within Eclipse right-click the file web2py.py and select Debug As -> Python Run
5. When a breakpoint is hit Eclipse will jump to the breakpoint where you can inspect variables and step thru the code

Answer (score 6):

You can also use Visual Studio 2010.  Here's how:

- Download and install [Python Tools for Visual Studio](http://pytools.codeplex.com/).
- Create a new project from existing code (*File > New > Project From Existing Code...*)
- Specify your web2py folder and use the defaults.
- Right-click on web2py.py and choose *Set as Startup File*.
- Set breakpoints and hit F5 (run) or right-click on web2py.py and choose *Start with Debugging*.

This is a nice setup if you already use visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, Due to the "span prevention" I am still not allowed to post screenshots, but here is a full screenshot hosted at my website:

http://static.techfuel.net/debug_web2py.png

Answer (score 1):

I'm debugging web2py applications with Eclipse and PyDev. Here is an article: 
http://www.web2pyslices.com/main/slices/take_slice/2

Answer (score 0):

As Carl stated, it is as easy as:

1. Installing PyDev in Eclipse
2. Right Click on your Web2Py project, selecting Debug As > Python Run
3. Selecting web2py.py as the file to run

No other plugins or downloads are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article on debugging python with pdb, which will work with web2py. http://sontek.net/debugging-python-with-pdb

Answer (score 0):

@Ned Batchelder is almost right, but the standard way of doing it in web2py is slightly different.

Instead of `import pdb; pdb.set_trace(), you use the code:

```
from gluon.debug import dbg
dbg.set_trace()
```

When executing the web application, the application will freeze when it reaches this section of code.  You then go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/debug/interact (using the root URL for your application) and it will show a fully interactive, web based debugger:

[image]

See [documentation](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/03/overview#Integrated-web-based-debugger).